# Видимость переменных и функций javascript

Tags: javascript

Сразу скажу, что js толком не изучал и я обычно все делаю методом подбора, уроков, научного тыка.

Написал для себя интересный сервис, вот сегодня решил почистить код, добавив переменные, но вот тут незадача: пробовал по разному, то какие-то переменные видит, то какие-то нет - в общем решил попросить вашей помощи.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Activator is not defined

Вот сам код:

```
if (location.hash.length == 134 || location.pathname == "/audios") {
  Audios();
}
Audio = document.getElementById("Player");

PUT = '\
<div class="AudiosBackground">\
<div class="AudiosTop">\
<input id="search" placeholder="Поиск..." oninput="Search();" onchange="Search();">\
<button id="exit">X</button></div>\
<div class="AudiosBottom">\
<button id="AudiosPause" class="AudiosUnit" style="display: none;"></button>\
<button id="AudiosPlay" class="AudiosUnit"></button>\
<button id="AudiosBack" class="AudiosUnit"></button>\
<button id="AudiosNext" class="AudiosUnit"></button>\
<button id="AudiosReload" class="AudiosUnit" title="Перезагрузить список"></button>\
<input type="range" onchange="AudiosVolume(this.value);" value="100" oninput="AudiosVolume(this.value);" id="AudiosVolume" class="AudiosUnit">\
<img src="/Audios/loading.gif" id="loading" style="display:none;">\
<a title="Нажмите, что-бы скачать." class="AudiosTitle" download></a>\
</div>\
<div class="AudiosIndicator">\
<div class="AudiosPlayed">\
</div>\
<div class="AudiosLoaded">\
</div>\
</div>\
<div class="AudiosBlock">\
</div>\
</div>';

Activator = "#PlayerActivator",
  Window = ".AudiosBackground",
  Block = ".AudiosBlock",
  Player = "#Player";

Play = "#AudiosPlay",
  Pause = "#AudiosPause",
  Prev = "#AudiosBack",
  Next = "#AudiosNext",
  Reload = "#AudiosReload";

PlayerTruck = ".PlayerTruck",
  PlayerTruckActive = ".PlayerTruckActive",
  PlayerTruckActiveHidden = ".PlayerTruckActiveHidden",
  PlayerTruckHidden = ".PlayerTruckHidden";

Truck = "#Truck",
  TruckNumber = $(Player).attr("number");

$(Activator).click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("use") == "1") {
    $(Window).fadeIn();
  } else {
    Audios();
  }
  return false;
});
 // Функция получения данных из строки (взял из паблика)
function HashParams(output) {
  var hashParams = {};
  var e, a = /\+/g,
    r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
    d = function(s) {
      return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " "));
    },
    q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  while (e = r.exec(q)) hashParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
  return hashParams[output];
}

function Audios() {
  var token = HashParams("access_token");
  var user = HashParams("user_id");
  history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
  if (token == null) {
    location.href = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=5569755&scope=Audio&redirect_uri=" + location.href + "&display=wap&response_type=token";
  } else {
    history.pushState(null, null, "/audios");
    $(Activator).attr("connect-url", "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id=" + user + "&access_token=" + token);
    connect = $(Activator).attr("connect-url");
    try {
      $.ajax({
        url: connect,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          $("body").append(PUT);
          console.log(connect);
          for (var i = 1; i < data.response.length; i++) {
            artist_ = data.response[i].artist;
            title_ = data.response[i].title;
            $(Block).append('<button title="' + artist_ + ' - ' + title_ + '" class="PlayerTruck" id="Truck' + i + '" onclick="AudioThis(&#039;' + data.response[i].url + '&#039;,&#039;' + [i] + '&#039;);">\
<span class="PlayerTitleAuthor">' + data.response[i].artist + '</span>\
<span class="PlayerTitleSong">' + data.response[i].title + '</span>\
</button>');
          }
          $(Window).fadeIn();
          $('#exit').click(function() {
            $(Window).fadeOut();
          });
          $(Pause).click(function() {
            $(Play).show();
            $(Pause).hide();
            if (Audio.duration != "0") {
              Audio.pause();
            }
          });
          $(Play).click(function() {
            $(Play).hide();
            $(Pause).show();
            if ($(Player).attr("number") == null) {
              $(Truck + '1').trigger('click');
            } else {
              Audio.play();
            }
          });
          $(Prev).click(function() {
            if (TruckNumber != null) {
              $("#Truck" + TruckNumber).prevAll(PlayerTruck).filter(":first").trigger('click');
            }
          });
          $(Next).click(function() {
            if (TruckNumber != null) {
              $("#Truck" + TruckNumber).nextAll(PlayerTruck).filter(":first").trigger('click');
            }
          });
          $(Reload).click(function() {
            $('#search').val("");
            $(Reload).prop("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
              url: connect,
              crossDomain: true,
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(data) {
                $(Reload).prop("disabled", false);
                $(Block).html("<!-- Список -->");
                for (var i = 1; i < data.response.length; i++) {
                  artist_ = data.response[i].artist;
                  title_ = data.response[i].title;
                  $(Block).append('<button title="' + artist_ + ' - ' + title_ + '" class="PlayerTruck" id="Truck' + i + '" onclick="AudioThis(&#039;' + data.response[i].url + '&#039;,&#039;' + [i] + '&#039;);"><span class="PlayerTitleAuthor">' + data.response[i].artist + '</span><span class="PlayerTitleSong">' + data.response[i].title + '</span></button>');
                }
              }
            });
          });
          $(Activator).attr('use', '1');
          $(Activator).attr('authorize', 'yes');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}

function AudioThis(url, id) {
  $("#download").attr("href", url);
  $(PlayerTruckActive).attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
  $(Player).attr("src", url);
  $(Player).attr("number", id);
  $(".AudiosTitle").html($("#Truck" + id).attr("title"));
  $(".AudiosTitle").attr("href", url);
  document.title = $(Truck + id).attr("title");
  Audio.play();
  $(Play).hide();
  $(Pause).show();
  Audio.onerror = function(e) {
    alert(e);
  };
  $(Truck + id).attr("class", "PlayerTruckActive");

  Audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $(PlayerTruckActive).attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    $(PlayerTruckActiveHidden).attr("class", "PlayerTruckHidden");
    $("#Truck" + TruckNumber).nextAll(PlayerTruck).filter(":first").trigger('click');
  });
  Audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    percent = 100 * Audio.currentTime / Audio.duration;
    $(".AudiosPlayed").attr("style", "width:" + ~~percent + "%;");
    if (isNaN(Audio.duration)) {
      $("#loading").show();
    } else {
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
  });
  Audio.addEventListener('progress', function() {});
}

function Search() {
  search = $('#search').val();
  if (search == '') {
    $(PlayerTruckHidden).attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    $(PlayerTruckActiveHidden).attr("class", "PlayerTruckActive");
  } else {
    $(PlayerTruck).attr("class", "PlayerTruckHidden");
    $(PlayerTruckActive).attr("class", "PlayerTruckActiveHidden");
    $(PlayerTruckHidden + "[title *= '" + search + "']").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    $(PlayerTruckActiveHidden + "[title *= '" + search + "']").attr("class", "PlayerTruckActive");
  }
}

function AudiosVolume(volume) {
  Audio.volume = volume / 100;
}
```

Веб: http://w-0rld.ru/Audios/audios.module.js

А вот старый, работающий код (Опасно для психики):

```
$('#PlayerActivator').click(function() {
  if ($("#PlayerActivator").attr("use") == "1") {
    $('.AudiosBackground').fadeIn();
  } else {
    Audios();
  }
  return false;
});

function HashParams(output) {
  var hashParams = {};
  var
    e,
    a = /\+/g,
    r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
    d = function(s) {
      return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " "));
    },
    q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  while (e = r.exec(q))
    hashParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
  return hashParams[output];
}

function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

function Audios() {
  var token = HashParams("access_token");
  var user = HashParams("user_id");
  history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
  if (token == null) {
    document.title = "Авторизация...";
    location.href = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=5569755&scope=audio&redirect_uri=" + location.href + "&display=wap&response_type=token";
  } else {
    history.pushState(null, null, "/audios");
    document.title = "Загрузка аудиозаписей...";
    $("#PlayerActivator").attr("connect-url", "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id=" + user + "&access_token=" + token);
    connect = $("#PlayerActivator").attr("connect-url");
    try {
      $.ajax({
        url: connect,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          $("body").append('<div class="AudiosBackground"><div class="AudiosTop"><input id="search" placeholder="Поиск..." oninput="Search();" onchange="Search();"><button id="exit">X</button></div><div class="AudiosBottom"><button id="AudiosPause" class="AudiosUnit" style="display: none;"></button><button id="AudiosPlay" class="AudiosUnit"></button><button id="AudiosBack" class="AudiosUnit"></button><button id="AudiosNext" class="AudiosUnit"></button><button id="AudiosReload" class="AudiosUnit" title="Перезагрузить список"></button><input type="range" onchange="AudiosVolume(this.value);" value="100" oninput="AudiosVolume(this.value);" id="AudiosVolume" class="AudiosUnit"><img src="/Audios/loading.gif" id="loading" style="display:none;"><a title="Нажмите, что-бы скачать." class="AudiosTitle" download></a></div><div class="AudiosIndicator"><div class="AudiosLoaded"></div></div><div class="AudiosBlock"></div></div>');
          try {
            for (var i = 1; i < data.response.length; i++) {
              artist_ = escapeHtml(data.response[i].artist);
              title_ = escapeHtml(data.response[i].title);
              $('.AudiosBlock').append('<button title="' + artist_ + ' - ' + title_ + '" class="PlayerTruck" id="Truck' + i + '" onclick="Audio(&#039;' + data.response[i].url + '&#039;,&#039;' + [i] + '&#039;);"><span class="PlayerTitleAuthor">' + data.response[i].artist + '</span><span class="PlayerTitleSong">' + data.response[i].title + '</span></button>');
            }
            $('.AudiosBackground').fadeIn();
            $('#exit').click(function() {
              $(".AudiosBackground").fadeOut();
            });
            var audio = document.getElementById("Player");
            $('#AudiosPause').click(function() {
              $('#AudiosPlay').show();
              $('#AudiosPause').hide();
              if (audio.duration != "0") {
                audio.pause();
              }
            });

            $('#AudiosPlay').click(function() {
              $('#AudiosPlay').hide();
              $('#AudiosPause').show();
              if ($("#Player").attr("number") == null) {
                $('#Truck1').trigger('click');
              } else {
                audio.play();
              }
            });
            $('#AudiosBack').click(function() {
              idnum = $("#Player").attr("number");
              if (idnum != null) {
                $("#Truck" + idnum).prevAll(".PlayerTruck:first").filter(":first").trigger('click');
              }
            });
            $('#AudiosNext').click(function() {
              idnum = parseInt($("#Player").attr("number"));
              if (idnum != null) {
                $("#Truck" + idnum).nextAll(".PlayerTruck:first").filter(":first").trigger('click');
              }
            });
            $('#AudiosReload').click(function() {
              $('#search').val("");
              $('#AudiosReload').prop("disabled", true);
              $.ajax({
                url: connect,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {
                  try {
                    $('#AudiosReload').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('.AudiosBlock').html("<!-- Список -->");
                    for (var i = 1; i < data.response.length; i++) {
                      artist_ = escapeHtml(data.response[i].artist);
                      title_ = escapeHtml(data.response[i].title);
                      $('.AudiosBlock').append('<button title="' + artist_ + ' - ' + title_ + '" class="PlayerTruck" id="Truck' + i + '" onclick="Audio(&#039;' + data.response[i].url + '&#039;,&#039;' + [i] + '&#039;);"><span class="PlayerTitleAuthor">' + data.response[i].artist + '</span><span class="PlayerTitleSong">' + data.response[i].title + '</span></button>');
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    alert("Не вышло обновить список. Ваша сессия устарела.");
                    $(".AudiosBackground").remove();
                    location.href = protocol + site + slesh + "audios";
                  }
                }
              });
            });
            $('#PlayerActivator').attr('use', '1');
          } catch (e) {
            alert("Не удалось загрузить ваши аудиозаписи. Ваша сессия устарела.");
            $(".AudiosBackground").remove();
          }
          document.title = "HR | Аудиозаписи";
          $('#PlayerActivator').attr('authorize', 'yes');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Не удалось получить список аудиозаписей. Проверьте соединение с интернетом.");
    }
  }
}

function onload() {
  if (location.hash.length == 134 || location.pathname == "/audios") {
    Audios();
  }
}

function Search() {
  search = $('#search').val();
  if (search == '') {
    $(".PlayerTruckHidden").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    $(".PlayerTruckActiveHidden").attr("class", "PlayerTruckActive");
  } else {
    $(".PlayerTruck").attr("class", "PlayerTruckHidden");
    $(".PlayerTruckActive").attr("class", "PlayerTruckActiveHidden");
    $(".PlayerTruckHidden[title *= '" + search + "']").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    $(".PlayerTruckActiveHidden[title *= '" + search + "']").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
  }
}


function Audio(url, id) {
  audio = document.getElementById("Player");
  $("#download").attr("href", url);
  $(".PlayerTruckActive").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
  $("#Player").attr("src", url);
  $("#Player").attr("number", id);
  $(".AudiosTitle").html($("#Truck" + id).attr("title"));
  $(".AudiosTitle").attr("href", url);
  document.title = $("#Truck" + id).attr("title");
  audio.play();
  $('#AudiosPlay').hide();
  $('#AudiosPause').show();
  audio.onerror = function() {
    alert("Данная композиция недоступна или у вас отсутствует соединение с интернетом.");
  };
  $("#Truck" + id).attr("class", "PlayerTruckActive");

  audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $(".PlayerTruckActive").attr("class", "PlayerTruck");
    idnum = $("#Player").attr("number");
    if (idnum != null) {
      $("#Truck" + idnum).nextAll(".PlayerTruck:first").filter(":first").trigger('click');
    }
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    audio = document.getElementById("Player");
    percent = 100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
    $(".AudiosLoaded").attr("style", "width:" + ~~percent + "%;");
    if (isNaN(audio.duration)) {
      $("#loading").show();
    } else {
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
  }, 500);
}

function AudiosVolume(volume) {
  new_volume = volume / 100;
  audio = document.getElementById("Player");
  audio.volume = new_volume;
}
```

Comment: В es5 переменные имеют скоуп функции. Если переменная не найдена в скоупе текущей функции то идет поиск в скоупе функции одним уровнем выше, и так далее рекурсивно.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Не совсем понял фразы: es5, скоуп функции.. Моей проблеме есть решение - пихать эти переменные в каждую функцию, но ведь можно же красиво как-то сделать? Подскажите что надо сделать для работоспособности?

Comment: Ох. Так изучите. Область видимости - это то чем js отличается от большинства других распространенных языков. Область видимости определяется функцией, а не {}

Comment: **var** Activator  =  "#PlayerActivator" ???

Comment: Так я могу сделать переменную что-бы она была видна везде?

Comment: es5 - "старый javascript". Сейчас еще есть новый javascript и в нем можно по-другому, но пока это вас не касается.

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: Activator is not defined_ - на какую именно строчку ругается?

Comment: $(Activator).click(function(){  (та которая идет самая первая после объявления переменных)

Comment: *js толком не изучал* (и, очевидно, не собираюсь), но вы тут в моей простыне разберитесь и скажите почему. Привет, хорошего настроения.

Comment: было подумал отформатировать но начал и бросил, уж больно страшно и много))

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, так лучше? :-)

Comment: @user224149, а у меня что-то нет такой ошибки при выполнении этого файла

Comment: Есть ли где-то в коде - `"use strict"`?

Comment: как используется этот код?

Comment: @Grundy божественно, мне стало жаль своего времени на работе, но глаз вырывало так что решил закрыть, если бы не твой коммент то не зашел бы сюда больше))

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, в сниппете есть кнопка: сделать красиво :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто напиши `var Activatore = "#PlayerActivator", ...`, как посоветовал Vyacheslav Danshin. Собственно var нужен и перед Play,PlayerTruck и Truck ниже по коду.

Comment: Так и сделал, похоже, работает. http://w-0rld.ru/audios